# How to force x11vnc to use Xfce?

Tags: xfce, x11vnc

I am trying to set up x11vnc with an Xubuntu 19.10 machine as the server and a Windows 10 Pro machine as the client.  For some reason, when I connect to the x11vnc server, the VNC viewer opens up a connection to the terminal.  This is not what I want; I want to be able to access the Xfce desktop.  I can access the desktop on the Xubuntu machine itself, and I can type `startxfce4` in the VNC session to get to an Xfce desktop, but I know there has to be an easier way.  What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that adding the `-usepw` flag allowed me to get to the Xfce desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonderful world of X11. There are several different ways to set up your X environment.

Option 1 is to use a display manager (`lightdm`, `gdm`, `xdm`, `kdm`) which automatically starts the X server, prompts you for your login info, and starts your X session which you can usually select. To get VNC running on display managers, see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/653221/how-can-i-set-up-x11vnc-to-start-on-boot-with-lightdm/653222#653222).

Option 2 is `xinit`. `xinit` allows you to start your X session directly from the console with two files, `~/.xinitrc` and `~/.xserverrc`. To start Xfce4 using `xinit` with VNC enabled, create `~/.xinitrc` and add the following commands:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
x11vnc & # start VNC as a job
xfce4-session # start xfce4
```