# How can I set up x11vnc to start on boot, with lightdm?

Tags: x11, vnc, remote-desktop, x11vnc

I have an X server all configured and running with LightDM and GNOME desktop. I have x11vnc installed to access the X server. I open a terminal in GNOME and run `x11vnc`. This gives me VNC access to the real X server, however I would like to start it automatically. I could put `x11vnc` in `~/.xprofile` to start in after I log in on LightDM, but what I would prefer is to start it immidiately after LightDM is started so that when I log in on VNC, I can see the LightDM prompt. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by adding a systemd service to start the x11vnc server `After=` LightDM is started. Ensure that the service is run under user `lightdm` so that you don't get pesky XAuthority `No protocol specified` errors.

/etc/systemd/system/x11vnc@.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
After=display-manager.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=lightdm
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -display %i                      
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

`After=display-manager.service` tells systemd that the display manager (LightDM) needs to be running before this service can be started.

`Type=simple` says that the process is non-forking, the command under `ExecStart` stays running for the duration of the VNC server's life.

`User=lightdm` says that the process under `ExecStart` should be run by user `lightdm`, a system user whose purpose is to run X clients for the duration of the LightDM login prompt. This user owns the X server, so in order to have applications run in the login prompt, you need to run them as this user.

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -display %i` is the command to run when this service is activated, it says to start `x11vnc` on display `%i`, which is referring to whatever comes after the "@" symbol when you start the service.

`Restart=always` says that whenever the service fails to start, try again.

`RestartSec=3` says to wait 3 seconds each time you retry.

`WantedBy=graphical.target` says to run the service whenever systemd brings up the graphical system (legacy runlevel 5).

To load the unit (make systemd "see" it), run the command

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
```

To enable it (make it start on boot), run the command

```
# systemctl enable x11vnc@<your-$DISPLAY-here>
```

where `<your-$DISPLAY-here>` is the X display that you want to give VNC access (usually `:0`)
To start it, run the command

```
# systemctl start x11vnc@<your-$DISPLAY-here>
```

Ditto about the `<your-$DISPLAY-here>`.

Note that you can run multiple independent services under the same unit file, by passing different displays after the "@". For example, you could run multiple VNC servers on X displays `:0`, `:1`, and `:2`, on ports `5900`, `5901`, and `5902` with `x11vnc@:0`, `x11vnc@:1`, and `x11vnc@:2`.